# Initializing the applicationhost.config file failed. Cannot find IIS Express

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I recently installed the Visual Studio 2017 RC and created AngularJS SPA application. I had to uninstall the VS 2017 RC as it was hanging multiple times. Now, Whenever I try to open this SPA application using VS 2015 I get this error. Any help to resolve this would be helpful. Thank you.

> Initializing the applicationhost.config file failed. Cannot find IIS
>   Express

[image: Error]

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes. I tried to uninstall and install the IIS, restarted the machine but no luck.

Comment: I got this when I inadvertently ran the IIS app rather than my own app. In the dropdown next to the green run arrow, select your up and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't fix this issue, But I managed to resolve  by Uninstalling and reinstalling the Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 10):

I have got the same issue.
So I install the IIS Express from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264

Then reload the solution. problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9Q8e7mRZ7_oaXRHX01yMUNPbUE

You need to modify the visual studio web services. The video shows how to modify VS. Modification depends on which type of template you are using that shows error. 
If its WCF, then you make web service updates during modification of VS.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on the site. Please read the rules.

Comment: I have made edits giving more explaination. Let me know if that is still an issue. I will delete my answer.

Comment: Please  check it again

Answer (score 0):

you can download IIS express from this link and install it

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264

Comment: Your answer is already a duplicate of other answers in this same post.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem while trying to "Live Share" my web development project on the web browser.
I was using the latest version of Visual Studio still I got this issue.
Then I go to the Visual Studio Downloader to download the ***ASP.NET and web development Workloads*** which is available in the Workloads section.
Here I had attached the image in which you can see in the details it is clearly written that Live Share is available.
[visual studio downloader where you can see the Live Share option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBpxA.png)